# Implementing a DAO for entity framework

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net

Could anybody help me to find a good tutorial about how can I implement DAO pattern and also tools that help me to create this classes in automated way.

Comment: Please note that I exchanged the repository tutorial link because the codeproject article was quite difficult and not straight to the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it might help you more to google for the [repository](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025102958/http://geekswithblogs.net/seanfao/archive/2009/12/03/136680.aspx) pattern. It's nearly the same as a DAO, only that DAOs can be finer grained while a repository usually just encapsulates an aggregate root. The principle behind both is the same, though.

As for the code generation: You could just setup a [T4 template](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/t4-text-template-transformation-toolkit-code-generation-best-kept-visual-studio-secret) for them or use an other template engine like NVelocity to create those DAOs automatically. However, if you implement DAOs/Repositories in a generic fashion, then there's little need for code generation in my opinion.

Here's also a [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150325045318/http://cgeers.com:80/2009/03/14/data-access-objects-with-the-entity-framework/) for implementing DAOs with entity framework.